# Map IEnumerable<MyClass> to a class

Tags: c#, reflection, automapper

I have a class called `MyClass` which has a bunch of properties (strings, bools, ints, etc).

I also have a `IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass>` collection which has key/value items.

I want to map this list of key/value items to the various properties in `MyClass`

Is there a way to do this with AutoMapper or another way with reflection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal method

```
SomeClass cls = new SomeClass();
Type type =  cls.GetType();
foreach (SomeOtherClass somecls in IEnumerableClass)
    type.GetProperty(somecls.KeyPropName).SetValue(cls, somecls.ValuePropName, null);
```

OR extension method if IEnumerable class is Key Value pair collection

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this IDictionary<string, dynamic> source) where T : class
{
    T obj = new T();
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> item in source)
        type.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(obj, item.Value, null);
    return obj;
}
```

use this like  below.

```
SomeClass somecls = IEnumerableClass.ToObject<SomeClass>();
```

OR

```
SomeClass somecls = ToObject(IEnumerableClass);
```